# Why can't proceed to UITableViewController when Facebook account logged in already?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I've been wondering why my code here isn't working.

On my LoginViewController where I handle the Facebook Login, I have this method where it should push to my UITableViewController when the user logged in already, but it doesn't work. What's wrong here?

```
    -(void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"You are logged in!";
    [self toggleHiddenState:NO];

    // Push to table view controller
    if(FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        UITableViewController *tvID = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tvID"];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:tvID animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, we're bad at random guessing - can you debug what the FBSession.activeSession.isOpen is returning?

Comment: Hi @LordT , I'm sorry but how would you do that? I'm just practicing facebook SDK. Thank you. Sorry for that.